# Blood transfusion

Tags: red-blood-cell

Can we exchange the antigen present on membrane of RBC's so that it can be transfused from one person to other ? 
As we face problem to find  required bloodgroup at the time of emergency especially O negative. So can we have some other technique to simplify our problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it's possible to change the blood types A & B into O, since the antigens for them have longer sugar chains than the O antigen (as seen on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ABO_blood_group_diagram.svg) picture from wikipedia). The problem is finding a  way of actually removing this extra sugar molecule(s) without destroying the viability of the blood cells.

An [attempt](http://2014.igem.org/Team:Tuebingen) was once made by a student team in the iGEM competition, but they were not successful - I don't know if anyone else ever tried it.

Comment: To be clear the iGEM team was partially successful they did remove most of the antigens,  but removing all the antigens present in the blood required an impractical amount of the enzyme being used.